# Can't "get" data in get ajax request using laravel

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, ubuntu, networking

I just can't retrieve the data in my query string section.

I've used AJAX request throughout my website to implement a wide variety of tasks asynchronously and didn't had an issue of this kind.

**Route**

```
Route::get('/mensagem/enviar_mensagem', [ 'as' => 'mensagem.enviar_mensagem', 'uses' => 'MensagemController@enviar_mensagem']);
```

the testing url:

```
http://mydomain.com.br/mensagem/enviar_mensagem?para=email@bol.com.br
```

my action method:

```
public function enviar_mensagem(Request $request)
{
     $para = $request->get('para');
    //$para = $_GET['para']; I get an undefined index error
    echo $para; //always empty string!
}
```

Comment: it turns out that was an Ngnix configuration issue. It was ignoring my query strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `input`. Like so:

Also, for testing, `return` versus `echo`.

```
public function enviar_mensagem(Request $request)
{
    $para = $request->input('para');    
    return $para;
}
```

***And to spark my curiosity,*** what does `return $request->all()` return?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the provided code seems to be correct. Make sure you `use \Illuminate\Http\Request`. This code

```
Route::get('/mensagem/enviar_mensagem', function(\Illuminate\Http\Request $request) {

    return $request->para;
//    return $request->get('para');  // also works  

});
```

returns `email@bol.com.br` by request `http://your-site.app/mensagem/enviar_mensagem?para=email@bol.com.br`

Comment: I had "use \Illuminate\Http\Request" included. I also tried to use "\Illuminate\Http\Request $request" in my action parameter list  and nothing. $request->para seems to return empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I copy pasted your code and both works:

```
$para = $request->get('para');
$para = $_GET['para'];
//$para = $_GET['para']; I get an undefined index error
```

Did you make sure the webserver is properly handling the HTTP request?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4#web-server-configuration

Comment: maybe this works: /index.php/mensagem/enviar_mensagem?para=email@bol.com.br

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code :

```
use Request;

class xyzController {
    public function enviar_mensagem()
    {
       $para = Request::all();
       echo $para['para']; 
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

First you will need to change the route to add also this

```
Route::get('/mensagem/enviar_mensagem/{para}',
 [ 'as' => 'mensagem.enviar_mensagem', 'uses' => 
'MensagemController@enviar_mensagem']);
```

And after that in controller

```
public function enviar_mensagem($para){
  return var_dump($para);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the route method on the request object to access GET parameters

```
public function enviar_mensagem(Request $request)
{
    $para = $request->route('para');

    echo $para;
}
```